# Is there a default email template

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-mail

In windoze, my email client has this text at the end of every email:

> Sent from Mail for Windows 10

Is there a way to set the email client in Elementary to do something like this:

> Sent from Mail for ElementaryOS

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished with a standard e-mail signature that will be appended to the end of the e-mail message.

Here's how: go to Accounts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>), click the account you want the signature on, click the edit icon at the bottom, under the composer section check the box for "Sign e-mails", then fill in whatever you would like it to say, then click Save.

Check it my writing a new message.  The signature should already be at the end of the message.